# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to get this scraper working by following the tutorial from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzZ3YOUhCxo

I have tried scraping amazon in case yellow pages wasn't working. I went from node 12 to node 13. I tried using full xpath. Disabled prettier in case the format on save caused an error.

Help I don't understand why this code isn't working. I swear to god I copy line by line from youtube.

```
(node:1740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at scrapeProduct (C:\Users\hello\coding\scrapy\server.js:8:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1740) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const [el] = page.$x('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h2/a/span');
  const src = await el.getProperty("src");
  const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();

  console.log({srcTxt});
}

scrapeProduct('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=cpa&geo_location_terms=New%20York%2C%20NY&page=1');
```

Comment: You left out an await in front of page.$x

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it... That was 2 hours of ???

Answer (score 1):

Always use try/catch in `async/await` whenever a promise is rejected which is awaited by await it will throw an error which should be catched by catch.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        const [el] = page.$x('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h2/a/span');
        const src = await el.getProperty("src");
        const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();


        console.log({ srcTxt });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, "ERROR");
    }
}

scrapeProduct('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=cpa&geo_location_terms=New%20York%2C%20NY&page=1');
```

Run the above code in your environment you will get to know what is causing the problem.